# Error in your SQL syntax updating multiple columns

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm attempting to update a MySQL table using C#, however I'm getting the error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0', exp_total='0', exp_perkPoints='0' WHERE uid='0'' at line 1

Below is the full query I'm attempting to execute with the values of the variables inserted.

```
UPDATE players SET cash='0', bankacc='0', coplevel='0',
    mediclevel='0', adminlevel='0',  arrested='0', blacklist='0',
    civ_alive='0, exp_level='0', exp_total='0', exp_perkPoints='0'
    WHERE uid='0'
```

I've checked that the column names are correct and they are.

I just can't seem to spot what is invalid about my query, I'm sure it's something basic. Can anyone spot what is wrong with it?

Cheers

EDIT - There is a single quotation mark after the uid='0 however it seems to have disapeared in the post

Comment: You say that you are attempting to update a MySQL table, but your error clearly shows that you are using MariaDB. Can you please clarify?

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly where your typo is.  You forgot to close a set of quotes.

Comment: Try taking the single quotes out.

Comment: That was it forgot a single quotes earlier in the string

Comment: Really????  You can't resolve this issue by yourself????  It's pretty clear from the color of the text that you're missing a quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

missing ' following zero: near civ_alive='0

original:

```
UPDATE players SET cash='0', bankacc='0', coplevel='0', mediclevel='0', 
    adminlevel='0', arrested='0', blacklist='0', civ_alive='0, 
    exp_level='0', exp_total='0', exp_perkPoints='0'
    WHERE uid='0'
```

should be to avoid error syntax:

```
UPDATE players SET cash='0', bankacc='0', coplevel='0', mediclevel='0', 
    adminlevel='0', arrested='0', blacklist='0', civ_alive='0', exp_level='0', 
    exp_total='0', exp_perkPoints='0'
    WHERE uid='0'
```

and regarding mariadb comments - mariadb is a fork of mysql so these are pretty similar, therefore would not make a problem out of it.